# Can asp.net JavascriptSerializer encode nulls as empty strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, javascriptserializer

I was wondering if it is possible to force the Microsoft JavascriptSerializer to encode `''` instead of `null` for null values in C#?

Comment: replace null with '' but not good solution.

Comment: Is this the Microsoft JSON serializer - [JavaScriptSerializer Class][ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: yes it is the Microsoft JSON serializer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You may achieve this by implementing custom [JavascriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx). Then you have to [use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your serializer.

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867506/convert-datatable-to-json-without-table-header/23868206#23868206) you will find an example that I prepared some time ago.